# Spectrum of the adjacency matrix of strongly regular graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am working through a proof of the following Theorem:
Let $G$ be a connected, $k$-regular graph, $G\neq K_n$, then $G$ is strongly regular if and only if $|Spec(G)|=3$.

Now I am having trouble with the given proof of the "$\Leftarrow$" direction:

Let $k,\beta_1,\beta_2$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Consider the matrix
    \begin{align*}
  M:=\frac{1}{(k-\beta_1)(k-\beta_2)}(A-\beta_1 I)(A-\beta_2 I),
 \end{align*}
    then $M$ has all of its eigenvalues equal to $0$ or $1$. This is, since if $b_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ to eigenvalue $\beta_i$, $i=1,2$, with $b_i\perp\mathbb{1}$, then
    \begin{align*}
  M\cdot b_1 =0,\\
  M\cdot b_2 =0,\\
  M\cdot\mathbb{1}=\mathbb{1}.
 \end{align*}
    Therefore $Spec(M)=\{1^{(1)},0^{(n-1)}\}$. Since $G$ is connected and because of the spectrum of $J$ (the $n\times n$ matrix with all 1's entries) as computed as $Spec(J)=\{1^{(1)},0^{(n-1)}\}$, we get $M=\frac{1}{n}\cdot J$. That is
    \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{n}\cdot J=\frac{1}{(k-\beta_1)(k-\beta_2)}(A-\beta_1 I)(A-\beta_1 I)(A-\beta_2 I).
 \end{align*}
    Factorising this out gives
\begin{align*}
   A^2=k\cdot I+\lambda\cdot A+\mu\cdot(J-I-A),
\end{align*}
which is a characterization of $G$ being strongly regular.

Now I doubt the implication to $M=\frac{1}{n}J$. For all we know, $M$ might be a diagonal matrix with a single $1$ and otherwise only $0$'s. Does this implication hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to note that the rank of $(A-\beta_1I)(A-\beta_2I)$ is 1,
and that its column space contains the all-ones vector. For this note that
$(A-\beta_1I)(A-\beta_2I)J = (k-\beta_1)(k-\beta_2)J$, where 
$(k-\beta_1)(k-\beta_2)\ne0$. Hence the sum of the columns of
$(A-\beta_1I)(A-\beta_2I)$ is a non-zero constant vector.